# establish openconnect without lose ssh connection

Tags: linux, ssh, openconnect

In my linux VPS, I want access to special web service that check my VPS IP, so i must use VPN.
but when establishing my VPN using openconnect , I'm lost ssh and control over my VPS ? any workaround to have VPN and access to my server public IP ?

Answer (score 1):

when you connect through VPN you lose route back to your ssh connection so you have to add route to keep this connection out of VPN tunnel.

```
ip rule add table 128 from <public-ip>
ip route add table 128 to <public ip subnet> dev eth0
ip route add table 128 default via <gateway>
```